# React useState hooks not updating render Text

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm using hooks to print a list of conversations, with the name of the contact and the last message for each.

I'm using an interval to check for each conversation if the last message has changed. It's working find with the API, I get the content and use setState to change it, but when I try to get it in the render part, I get the old one.

Here is some code:

```
const _getMessages = () => {
    setDataMsg('');
    if (dataContacts) {
        dataContacts.map((itemValue, itemIndex) => {
            ApiClient.instance.getConversation(itemValue.id).then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    setDataMsg([...dataMsg, response.data[response.data.length-1].content]);
                    console.log('getting all messages ', response.data[response.data.length-1].content);
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                Alert.alert('Erreur', 'Impossible de récupérer les messages')
            })
        })
    }
    else
        clearInterval(intervalMsg);
    if (props.navigation.state.routeName !== "MessagesPage") {
        clearInterval(intervalMsg);
    }
}



// Affichage du dernier message //
    const _showMessage = (index) => {
        if (dataMsg) {
            return (dataMsg[index]);
        }
        return ('Aucun message');
    }
```

And the render:

```
<FlatList
                        style={getStyle().messageList}
                        data={dataContacts}
                        extraData={dataMsg}
                        refreshing={true}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => {
                            return item.id.toString();
                        }}
                        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                            return (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={getStyle().card}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        cardClickEventListener(item)
                                    }}>
                                    <View style={getStyle().cardImage}>
                                        <Image style={getStyle().image}
                                               source={_handleImg(item)}/>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={getStyle().cardContent}>
                                        <Text
                                            style={[getStyle().name, {fontFamily: props.font}]}>{item.firstName + " " + item.lastName}</Text>
                                        <Text
                                            style={{fontFamily: props.font, fontStyle:'italic'}}>{_showMessage(index)}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={getStyle().cardIndicator}>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            )
                        }}/>
```

Comment: Did you tried setting the data that is displayed in list as extradata?

Comment: Yes, it's what I did !